# Error setting up Django registration

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-registration

So, I'm trying to set up `registration` and I keep getting the error

> Unhandled exception in thread started by
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/**init**.py", line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
>       app_config.ready()
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
>       self.module.autodiscover()
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/**init**.py", line 26, in autodiscover
>       autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
>       import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/admin.py", line 2, in 
>       from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 83, in 
>       class Site(models.Model):
>
> File "//anaconda/envs/hellovenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 102, in **new**
>       "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
>
> RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sites.models.Site doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

after running

```
pip install django-registration-redux==1.1
```

and my `INSTALLED_APPS` are

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'collection', # this is the app we added
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'registration',
]
```

Not being super familiar with python tracebacks I'm not sure which files to modify to fix this.

Thanx.

Comment: could you post the `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

from [docs](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#settings),

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'registration',
    # ...other installed applications...
)
```

`django.contrib.sites` seems to be omitted in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: is this the same error? and have you done the migration after setting up? the migration is necessary.

Comment: No it's a different error, and migration ends the same way: `ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite`

Comment: I guess you go for the update to the version 1.3...for [this reason](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/issues/132). Hope this helps...